# Dankbarkeit für Öffnen eines Geschäfts ausdrücken

Tags: word-choice, formality, letter

Ich möchte mich mit einem Brief bei einem Restaurant bedanken, das nur zur Sommersaison offen hat. Im Normalfall würde ich einfach sagen:

> Danke fürs Aufmachen.

Ich denke im sprachlichen Gebrauch ist das für jeden verständlich, aber in dieser Form kann man das nicht in einem Brief schreiben.

Was ist eine gute Alternative?

Comment: Rechtschreibung bitte :)... geht's ums "Eröffnen", ums tägliche Öffnen, oder ums für den Sommer Öffnen? Bei letzterem würde ich sagen "Danke, dass ihr auf habt/ Danke fürs aufhaben/aufsein."... "Aufmachen" klingt meiner Ansicht nach zu tagaktuell

Comment: Ich habe die Frage mal etwas umstrukturiert, aber dennoch wäre es hilfreich, wenn Du ein paar mehr Details bezüglich der Situation und was die gesuchte Alternative leisten sollte, hinzufügen könntest.

Comment: Wofür willst Du danken? Für's Aufmachen? Dass Du nicht draußen stehen musst, sondern rein kannst, Dich setzen? Wenn es regnet? "Danke, dass Sie im Sommer öffnen."

Comment: Da fehlt wieder einmal komplett der Kontext, und es ist für niemanden verständlich, warum man sich hier bedanken sollte. Außer es wäre gemeint: "Danke, dass ihr euren miesen Laden wenigstens im Winter geschlossen haltet".

Answer (score 2):

Danke, dass Ihr in der Sommersaison geöffnet habt.

Danke, dass Ihr in der Sommersaison das Restaurant betreibt.

Danke für das Betreiben des Restaurants während der Sommermonate.

Danke für den Restaurantbetrieb im Sommer.

Danke für die Bewirtschaftung des Restaurants zur Sommersaison.